# How to handle Vertical tab (ASCII 11) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file which has few lines in it. One of the lines has a "Vertical Tab" character in it (ASCII control character, ASCII code is 11). Python program (v 2.7) is just trying to read the file line by line and doing some basic operations. It is failing while reading it and I am assuming it is breaking the line the moment it encounters the special character.

How do we handle this character. I am ok either replacing it with a space or deleting it.

```
import sys
import os
import codecs

v_filename=str(sys.argv[1])

if not os.path.exists(v_filename):
        print('Data file not found'+v_filename)
        sys.exit(1)

v_out_file=str(v_filename)+'_converted'
print(v_out_file)

with codecs.open(v_filename,'r',"utf-8") as file:
        with codecs.open(v_out_file,'w',"utf-8") as v_variable_file:
                linesf=file.readlines()
                header_line=str(linesf[0])
                tralier_line=str(linesf[-1])

                if (header_line[0:17]).strip() == "Accounts1File" :
                        v_variable_file.write((header_line[0:17])+'|'+(header_line[17:20])+'|'+(header_line[20:28])+'|'+(header_line[28:36])+'|'+(header_line[36:44])+'\n')
                else:
                        print("Header identifier not matching")

                file.seek(0)

                for line in file:
                        v_keyword=str(line[0:17]).strip()
                        if v_keyword == "AcctSummary" :
                                v_variable_file.write(line[0:17]+'|'+line[17:67]+'|'+line[67:117]+'|'+line[117:372]+'|'+line[372:382]+'|'+line[382:412]+'\n')
                        elif v_keyword == "CustSummary" :
                                v_variable_file.write(line[0:17]+'|'+line[17:67]+'|'+line[67:117]+'|'+line[117:132]+'|'+line[132:136]+'\n')
                        elif v_keyword == "ProfileActivity" :
                                v_variable_file.write(line[0:17]+'|'+line[17:57]+'|'+line[57:157]+'|'+line[157:207]+'|'+line[207:226]+'\n')
                        elif v_keyword == "Accounts1File" or v_keyword == "AgentFile":
                                pass
                        else:
                                print("NOT IN SCOPE:"+line)
                                sys.exit(1)
```

Above is what I am trying to do.

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is in `linesf=file.readlines()`? If so, most of the other code is irrelevant. Post an example program that focuses on the problem, omitting other stuff. And include sample data. You may find that `StringIO.StringIO("foo\x0bbar\n")` is a sufficient test buffer.

Comment: "I am assuming it is breaking the line the moment it encounters the special character.": possibly, yes. `\v` is considered for line splitting when using [`unicode.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.splitlines), but not when using `readlines`. Then again, opening as UTF-8 with `codecs` may result in the unicode behaviour, even by `readlines`.

Comment: That is obviously NOT your code, since that code is Python 3.  Show us YOUR code, and show us where it is failing.

Comment: I have out the code above, it prints error message with line of file having issues ("NOT IN SCOPE:" + line). can't print here but it prints the line which has this special character in it and it is confirmed that it is Vertical tab. I want to read the file line oy line by either replacing it with space or deleting it

Comment: It is breaking at the special character hence not finding one of 3 v_keyword mentioned under if/elif conditions

Comment: @TimRoberts Curious: what is the part here that indicates it is specifically Python 3?

Comment: Hold up: did you just added a large amount of essential code to your question that wasn't there during the first set of comments?

Comment: @9769953  Parens on the print statement is the big clue.  Admittedly, I misread this and thought they were calling `open` instead of `codecs.open`, so the clues are not definitive.

Comment: It is true that Python treats `\v` vertical tab as an end-of-line character.  If that's not desirable, you may have to read the whole file as a single block and do `data.split('\n')`.

Comment: @TimRoberts When you wrote, "That is obviously NOT your code, since that code is Python 3. Show us YOUR code, and show us where it is failing." ... are you complaining about the question tags? `python 2.x` is a search tag, but `python 3.x`  is not a search tag?

Comment: I don't remember,.  This post is a year old, and has been edited multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of vertical tabs (`\v == chr(11)`) and other strange characters by using the following function:

```py
def sani(whole:str) ->str:
    result = "\\".join(repr(part)[1:-1] for part in whole.split("\\"))
    return result
```

Suppose we use the following string as a test input:

```py
test_fish = (3 * "\\").join(['\n', 'tuna', chr(7), 'anchovy', "\r", 'salmon', 'trout'])
test_fish = '\n\\\\\\tuna\\\\\\\x07\\\\\\anchovy\\\\\\\r\\\\\\salmon\\\\\\trout'
```

The output from `sani` is shown below:

```
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
```

Note that it does not matter how many times we sanitize the string to get rid of special characters.
The output will not change after the first run:

```py
for _ in range(0, 5):
    r = sani(test_fish)
    print(r)
```

```
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
```